# What's the difference of kernel files built by dart and flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

What's the difference of the output from the following two cmds:

```
dart --snapshot=hello.dart.snapshot --snapshot-kind=kernel a.dart arguments-for-training 
flutter build bundle // build/app.dill
```

Are those kernel outputs the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter uses a modified Dart SDK that contains `dart:ui` but not `dart:html`.
The compilation step is the same because Flutter builds upon Dart.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the size of flutter kernel file ?

Comment: For what purpose? If it's about smaller Flutter deployables, the Dart and Flutter team are constantly exploring possibilities to reduce the size. As far as I understand there is still potential but the known approaches require more and more effort.

Comment: I am considering to run flutter from kernel in some case. But the size is a matter. I find that there are sources codes without compression and tree shaking in app.dill.

Comment: Why does size matter? Can you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: The size of the kernel output built from a demo project is larger than 15M. I am considering to use kernel file for dynamic rendering (like js, just download some assets and run it), but I am not sure it can work.

Comment: That's too abstract for me. I'd suggest to ask in Dart Google groups. Several Dart Team members monitor them while only few monitor SW questions.

Comment: It's possible to create a core snapshot using app.dill built by `flutter build bundle` ?

Comment: Sorry, fon't know.